# How do I make the font size a % of it's div?

Tags: css

I have a header inside a percentage based div and what the font size to adjust when the size of this div changes i have read the question on [Viewport Sized Fonts](http://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) (vw, vh, vim) but unfortunately those aren't supported by chrome yet.

```
.intro-text {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 30%;
    height: 343px;
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: -172.5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

There has to be a way to do this in CSS...

Comment: you might be better off using javascript to measure the height of the div and set the height of the font in pixels. i dont think you can do what you're asking in css.

Answer (score 0):

In current CSS2 and CSS3, you cannot set `font-size` of a `div` relative to anything but the `font-size` of the parent `div`, except in CSS3 where you can set it to the viewport (I believe this is supported, but buggy), but not relative to the parent `div` `width`.

You can use javascript to measure the `div` and set the `font-size` of a child `div`, but a better idea might be to use an image of text that can resize itself by having `width: 100%`, so that it always fills the parent `div` exactly.